# Facebook sharing wrong feature image wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I am using [simple sharer button](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/simple-share-buttons-adder) and post shot-code on our blog page see here

http://www.techverx.com/blog/

I have multiple blogs when i click share on any blog facebook pick the latest blog not that one which i click its because og tags.

Also i debug my url with facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ it shows me that, facebook get only that post which is present in og tags.

Any idea how i solve this ?

Comment: _“I have multiple blogs”_ – I think you actually mean, you have multiple _blog entries_ on your site? You need to pass the permalink of the single entry to the share dialog – right now you are passing only the base URL `http://www.techverx.com/blog/` to it, so of course it shares only that, and not an individual entry.

Comment: @CBroe, yeah you are right but the problem is i am using short-code and there is no way that how i pass permalink. I think for that we need to either change the plugin or customize that plugin. 

Thanks